# How can I make framer-motion always animate my array in useState when it gets rerendered/changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I have set up a sandbox to illustrate my problem: [Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-mcclintock-cgnqxg?file=/src/App.js)

When you click 'All' and then a year, it doesnt animate the boxes. It also skips animating the other way around on the elements from a specific year. If you click a year and then 'All'. Only new elements are animated.

How could I solve this with framer-motion?

I have tried using the key propery on the **<motion.div>** element but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. What I needed was to put **layout** prop on the **<motion.div**. You can read more about it here: [layout animations](https://www.framer.com/motion/layout-animations/)

I updated my codesandbox with that **prop**. You can view the working codesandbox here: [Working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-mcclintock-cgnqxg?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `<AnimatePresence>` with some additional props. Here is an example [link to codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-neumann-37pmj4)

```
export default function App() {
const [persons, setPersons] = useState(arr);

function handleChange(e) {
  // ...
}

return (
  <>
...
...
    <div style={{ display: "grid", gap: "1rem", justifyItems: "center" }}>
      <AnimatePresence>
        {persons.map((person) => (
          <Person name={person.name} year={person.year} key={person.name} />
        ))}
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  </>
);
}
```

Animation Properties for `<motion.div>`

```
const itemAnimation = {
  initial: { opacity: 0, scale: 0.2 },
  animate: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
  transition: { duration: 1 },
  exit: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 }
};
```

Your Each Array item div should look like

```
function Person({ name, year }) {
  return (
    <motion.div
      key={name + year}
      className="motion-div"
      variants={itemAnimation}
      initial="initial"
      animate="animate"
      exit="exit"
    >
      <p>
        {name} - {year}
      </p>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not what i want. if you look at my provided codesandbox, and you click from year to year. thats the kind of animation i want. your solution has an exit animation, but it doesnt animate a year if you click 'All' =>  year.